# Is there a default time-out for asynchronous tests running in protractor.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, jasmine-node

I have a angular application. I have written some test cases for the login-page, checking normal login scenarios.

```
describe('Login screen tests', function () {
  var ptor = protractor.getInstance();

  beforeEach(function(){
    ptor.get('http://url:3000/login/#/');
  });

  it('Blank Username & Password test', function() {
    ptor.findElement(protractor.By.id("submit")).click();
    var message = ptor.findElement(protractor.By.repeater('message in messages'));
    message.then(function(message){
        expect(message.getText()).toContain('Username or Password can\'t be blank');
    });
  });

  it ('Blank Password test', function(){
    ....
  });

  it ('Invalid username test', function(){
    ....
  });    

  ......  //Similarly more test cases folow for the login screen. 
});
```

The tests run properly as expected.

Problem: The tests are very slow, this takes about 1.5 mins to complete. If I run the same tests using a selenium via java. It takes only around 2-3 seconds which should be ideal. 
I want to use protractor coz the application is entirely on top of angular.

I would guess that there maybe a default time-out of lets say 300ms after each tests. which make the tests slow. So even if the check is done it waits for the time-out.

Is there some polling mechanism so that if the test completes before time-out it can move forward. I tried using `done()` like in jasmine, but `done()` gives an error, i inquired to know that `done()` is internally pached with `protractor`.

Comment: I don't understand how changing the `timeout` would make your tests run faster... Btw, about using `done()` in Protractor tests: [GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/659).

Comment: What i meant is if the test completes before the default time-out it would still wait for that to complete. Even i thought of using done(), but it gives me errors, https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/658, i raised this issue and it turns out i cant use done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a chance the slowness is related to protractor waiting to sync with each page each time.
You can disable that feature with

```
ptor.ignoreSynchronization = true;
```

Keep in mind that the option was intended to be passed to non-angular pages, temporary.
But if speed is more important to you, i guess you can go with that.

Note `ptor` is the old syntax, you should upgrade and start using `browser` instead, like this:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
```

If you start experiencing flaky tests, i suggest you go back to the default `false` value on the specific pages that has random issues.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @elgalu. I tried it and the speed was drastically improved. But ya it causes problems for some of the tests and runs well for others. I tried to dig deep. It seems there some waiting time for all the tests but there should be a way so that if the test completes before the time it should go to the next.  Anyways i will except this answer.